# How come doesn't the green box go to the bottom-right of the page but it stays there?

Tags: html, css

The image has the code and the output. I am an amateur and I am only learning so I hope you can help me!

[image]

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first. Then read [ask] and edit your question to meet that guideline. After that, add a [repro] for debugging details.

Comment: I highly doubt you are going to fix the question. So I will at least help you this way. Use `position: absolute` if you want to set specific position with `bottom: 0px; right: 0px`. When you use `position: relative` it only moves the div by the specific amount, but not to that position. [Link to w3schools page about positioning.](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

Answer (score -2):

I'm assuming that you are referring to position: fixed? Position: fixed makes an element stay relative to the viewport, even if you scroll up or down. For more information click [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp).

Comment: Do not guess into the blue. Questions that do not meet the guidelines and missing debugging details should not be answered in the first place. Flag those question accordingly or comment it and ask for clarifications.